# I want to distribute small amount of bitcoins

Tags: transaction-fees

What should I be aware when I want distribute say 0.0001 bitcoin to 50 bitcoin wallets.
I this be done with one transaction? what are the implication of transaction fees?

I want my students to experience the bitcoin phenomena.

Answer (score 1):

I read this on bitcoinfees.com

If any of the outputs (including any change) of your transaction are less than 0.01 BTC, then a fee of 0.0005 BTC is required.

This is called bitcoin dust. Smaller transactions as you intend todo comes with a fee.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see the point in giving each student 0.000002 bitcoin, they cannot do anything with it as it is less than the transaction fee.

I'd recommend you to split maybe 1 BTC or 0.5 BTC amongst your student, to that they can actually use the coins.

For the practical side of the question, this can (and should) be done in a single transaction to reduce data overhead. Bitcoin allows to specify multiple inputs and outputs in a transaction, so you can take some bitcoins from your wallet and send some amount to 50 different addresses. However though, I think the original Qt client does not support this. (**EDIT**: As julian-goldsmith pointed out in his [comment](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11696/i-want-to-distribute-small-amount-of-bitcoins/11701?noredirect=1#comment15265_11701), it does seem to have this functionality after all.)

You could consider using a more advanced wallet like Armory (I have no experience with MultiBit or Electrum, maybe they can do the job as well). I think the web-wallet on [Blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/wallet/) supports multiple outputs as well.

As long as the outputs are sufficiently big, like Filip says bigger than 0.01 BTC, you will not have to pay a fee, but of course you always can to support miners.

Comment: I don't have it up, but if I remember correctly, the Qt client has a "+" next to the address you're sending bitcoins to, that will let you add more addresses.